# VBA Excel Formatting String with multiple periods

Tags: excel, vba, format

I'm working with government harmonized codes. They're formatted as 10 numbers with periods between the 4th and 5th characters, and six-seventh characters like this "1234.56.7890". I'm trying to do some validation work so when a user enters a number without the periods, which is often the case, it puts the periods in for them.

The harmonized code is a variable in this instance named dimmed `tv` as a string.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
tv = Format(tv, "####.##.####")
```

Problem is, when I input `1234567890`, it converts it instead to `1234567890..` with the two periods at the end. Any idea how I can get it to convert it to `1234.56.7890` as my code implies it should?

Comment: Remove all existing periods, then put them in the correct places by concatenating them with `Left(tv, 4)/Mid(tv, 5, 2)/Right(tv, 4)`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Tim. You've been a tremendous help as always. Remade to "tv = Left(tv, 4) & "." & Mid(tv, 5, 2) & "." & Right(tv, 4)" and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim e
    For Each e In Array("1234.56.7899", "123456.7899", "1234.567899", _
                        "1234567899", "123A567899", "123456789")
        Debug.Print e, ValidTv(e)
    Next e
End Sub

'check format and return normalized value if possible
'  return empty string if valid value can't be created
Function ValidTv(ByVal tv As String) As String
    If tv Like "####.##.####" Then
        ValidTv = tv
    Else
        tv = Replace(tv, ".", "")
        If tv Like "##########" Then
            ValidTv = Left(tv, 4) & "." & Mid(tv, 5, 2) & "." & Right(tv, 4)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```